# Proper index for var1 IN (1, 2, ...) GROUP BY (var2) ORDER BY SUM(var3) LIMIT X

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize the following query:

```
            SELECT name  
            FROM  tbl 
            WHERE user_id
                IN (".$user_ids.") 
            GROUP BY name ORDER BY SUM(counter) DESC LIMIT 10
```

Tbl info: name is VARCHAR, counter and user_id are INTs. user_id, name is unique.

I've tried adding `IDX(user_id, counter, name)` but in `EXPLAIN` I'm still seeing `Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort` so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

What is the proper index for such a query?

Comment: You can try the index `tbl(user_id, name, count)`, but MySQL might still choose to do a file sort for the `group by`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Both seem to work pretty much the same (which is too slow). Weird thing is without a `USE INDEX` he uses `tbl(name)` which is performing MUCH worse. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Can you provide us a create table structure?.

Answer (score 1):

The following might improve your performance:

```
select t.name,
      (select sum(counter) from tbl t2 where t2.name = t.name) as sumcounter
from (select distinct name
      from tbl
      where user_id IN (".$user_ids.")
     ) t
order by sumcounter desc;
```

Now put indexes on `tbl(user_id, name)` and on `tbl(name, counter)`.

If this works, it is because the inner subquery is using the first index to get the distinct names.  The nested subquery in the `select` would use the second index to calculate the count.

I don't like rewriting queries like this.  On occasion it might be necessary to get the performance you need.

Comment: I took the courage to fix the typo in select

Answer (score 1):

The correct index is `IDX(user_id, name, counter)`, but the query needs additional computations after the data is taken from the index. If the amount of different names is about 10 there is hardly anything you can do (the most of the time is taken by the sum operation), but if there are many different names, you can reduce sorting by using some empirical knowledge about the `SUM(counter)` threshold:

```
SELECT name  
FROM  tbl 
WHERE user_id IN (".$user_ids.") 
GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(counter) > 1000 -- adjust the threshold 
ORDER BY SUM(counter) DESC LIMIT 10
```

UPD1. Hm, if you say that you've tried the `IDX(user_id, name, counter)` index and the performance is the same, I actually can not see the reason why it is slow, unless you pass several hundred user ids (in which case the time is spent for the query parsing and not for the execution).

UPD2. MySQL [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator does some additional magic:

> Returns 1 if expr is equal to any of the values in the IN list, else returns 0. If all values are constants, they are evaluated according to the type of expr and sorted. The search for the item then is done using a binary search.

That means if you pass INT values into the operator `IN (1,2,3)`, they are sorted as INTS, if you serialize integers that are stored as strings `IN ('1', '11', '111', '12')` they are sorted in lexicographical order. The rationale of the sorting is to eliminate random index reads, which is significant when you pass a lot of values into the operator.

Comment: I'm actually passing 5k user ids, and I understand this can take time, but 5-6seconds sounds way too much.

Comment: @Noam, in this case you have a long query, and it really takes time to  parse the query. How do you get the ids? It might be better to get them using a JOIN with another table, is there an option?

Comment: That is possible. You think a major part of 5seconds can be parsing of the 5k user_ids?

Comment: @Noam, I almost sure. In my experience, when you pass more then 800-1000 ids, it is better to reorganize something, otherwise the parsing becomes too significant.

Comment: @Noam, BTW, `IN` operator sorts its arguments before applying them, so make sure you serialize ids as INTs, otherwise, they will be sorted incorrectly and introduce additional overhead because of random index reads.

Comment: I don't fully follow. Is there a difference between a string of IDs (generated from implode) from `serialized` ids you mentioned? Can you elaborate?